# Django, override static path the url routes

Tags: python, django, static-files

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

My static path:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public/'),
)

STATIC_URL = '/'
```

Esentially, I want urlpatterns to override static files.  if a route is found in urlpatterns, go to that route, else, go to static.

At the moment, all urlpatterns return 404 because they are not found in the static dir.  What can I do to solve this?